# OSError: no library called "cairo-2" was found - I am using mac m1 chip

Tags: python, macos, apple-m1, cairo

I tried to install it using brew:  `brew install cairo`.

Then added the following line to my `.bashrc` and `.zshrc` file:

`export DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH`

But it is still giving me the same error.

I even tried those:

1. `brew install cairo pango gdk-pixbuf libxml2 libxslt libffi`
2. `pip install pipwin pipwin install cairocffi`

I tried to run a flask project which had some dependencies in a mac m1 and it is giving me this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to go to your Applications -> Utilities in your mac and there will be  `Terminal` right click it click `Get Info` then check `Open using Rosetta`.

Then open a terminal and write:

```
brew install cairo
brew install pango
```

To do this you should have installed Homebrew you can check the [brew docs](https://brew.sh/).